# Spring security PreAuthorize SPEL for authority names contains "ROLE_ADMIN"

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

I have authorities names as:
"ROLE_ADMIN"
"ROLE_ADMIN_L1"
"ROLE_ADMIN_L2"
"ROLE_ADMIN_L3"
...

In @PreAuthroize("..."), can I use SPEL to check whether the authority name contains "ROLE_ADMIN" instead of list all the names in "hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN_L1','ROLE_ADMIN_L2','ROLE_ADMIN_L3',...)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way.

SPEL is able to get principal, so the solution is to check all authorities in the principal.authorities and search for the authority whose name starts with "ROLE_ADMIN". The snippet of the code is as below:

**@PreAuthorize("#principal.authorities.?[authority.startsWith('ROLE_ADMIN')].size() > 0")**
public Object apiName(Principal principal) {...}

The expression "#principal.authorities.?[authority.startsWith('ROLE_ADMIN')]" will return an array with all the authority names that start with "ROLE_ADMIN". If the array size is greater than 0, the user has the permission to invoke the method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use [Springs hierarchical roles](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/authz-arch.html#authz-hierarchical-roles). That way you can configure that all ROLE_ADMIN_L1... are also ROLE_ADMIN.

Example from the docs

```
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF
            ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`ROLE_ADMIN ⇒ ROLE_STAFF ⇒ ROLE_USER ⇒ ROLE_GUEST`

So you would need something like this:

```
<property name="hierarchy">
    <value>
        ROLE_ADMIN_L1 > ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_ADMIN_L2 > ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_ADMIN_L3 > ROLE_ADMIN
    </value>
</property>
```

and use `@PreAuthroize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`

Comment: That's not what I want. ROLE_ADMIN has global authority. ROLE_ADMIN_XXX has different subsets of the APIs that ROLE_ADMIN can invoke. I am looking for the simple solution on @PreAuthroize("hasAnyAuthority('')) annotation instead of listing a number of ROLE_ADMIN_XXX in the annotation

Comment: AFAIK what you want is not possible with the built-in tools of Spring, you can look at the implementation for `hasAnyAuthority` [here][https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ce20cfcb9803a6175f6befc9008cadcc4e3b6d72/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.java], it does a simple contains on a set of roles.